# Универсальное решение проблем с кириллицей C++

Tags: c++, кириллица, locale

Веду разработку на операционной системе macOS. Возникают кучи проблем с кириллицей (string или char*), например, при работе с функциями regex, ::tolower/::toupper и тд.

При запросе locale в терминале, имею следующее:

```
LANG="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Использую C++11. Boost принципиально использовать не хочу и, желательно, чтобы решение могло быть перенесено в будущем на линкус (отсылка к непереносимому codecvt).

Собственно сам вопрос: как можно исправить проблему кириллицы во всей программе? Например, использовать грамотно locale.h (и как это - грамотно?) или что-нибудь еще.

UPD:

Вывод текста я осуществляю непосредственно в консоль. В консоль вывод происходит отлично, вот только преобразования через transform, используя параметры ::tolower, ::toupper успешно игнорируются. Используя codecvt я смог получить из string -> wstring, выполнил ::tolower и смог так же сделать wstring->string, однако, это явный "костыль" и использовать его всегда, когда мне надо что-то сделать с байтами строки - не выход.

Если я вывожу русский текст в ncurses, получается так: 
(Я какой-то текст) "Я какой-?~Bо ?~Bек?~A?~B"

Comment: а в какой среде разрабатываете???

Comment: @Alex.B для практичности я использую GCC (g++)

Comment: Пожадуйста, поясните о каких проблемах идет речь? То есть вопрос надо сузить он слишком общий.

Comment: @Cerbo "Я какой-то текст" отображается как "Я какой-?~Bо ?~Bек?~A?~B"

Comment: @ЯковЛинг Где отображается? И уточнения надо в вопрос добавлять, его можно править. Такие здесь правила.

Comment: @Cerbo хорошо, спасибо, добавил UPD к вопросу

Comment: @ЯковЛинг Все равно проблема не понятна, вам поэтому и не отвечают. Лучше вопросы писать в духе: хочу получить это, делаю то-то (код привести), но получаю другое.

Comment: выберете **одну** проблему, которая у вас есть (к примеру, "как вывести русский текст, используя ncurses"). Создайте **минимальный** пример кода, который демонстрирует проблему. Опишите *словами*, что код по вашему должен делать и что вместо этого происходит (желаемый и действительный вывод буквально приводите, не пересказывайте). [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Очень понимаю ваше желание не использовать Boost(тоже такой принцип).

Что бы раз и навсегда забыть о проблемах с кодировкой лучше всего использовать utf8 и в STL есть его реализация `wstring`.

```
wstring str = u8"кириллический текст";//u8 преобразует ansi символы в utf8.
```

Используя `wstring` о проблемах с локалью можно забыть.

Из плюсов это переносимость на всё что угодно, а из минусов это повышенное потребление памяти(не смертельно но всё же).

И, кстати говоря, считается правилом хорошего тона не использовать `std::wcout` и `std::cout` (равно как и пару `std::wcin` и `std::cin`) в пределах одного приложения(есть проблемы их совместного использования).

Comment: Только вот с вводом  wstring (wchar) есть по крайней мере 2 проблемы. 1) Нельзя смешивать однобайтное и wide-character чтение  (cin/wcin (а также cout/wcout, кстати) т.е.  `getchar()` и ее аналоги  с `getwchar()` и др.) и 2) если ввод содержит неверную для локали wide-character последовательность, то это приводит к невосстановимой ошибке чтения (как следствие, читать что-то вроде дампа базы, содержащее смесь произвольных двоичных данных и текста таким образом не получится)

Comment: @avp С первым не согласен. однобайтовые(ansi) символы отлично помещаются в wchar(просто потому что wchar больше), а utf8 устроен так то ansi символы == utf8 символам. А со вторым да. Вы абсолютно правы. и тут решение только с конвертацией кодировки. На ум приходит Boost::locale но я уверен что есть другие библиотеки для конвертации. Но мне кажется что второе я не правильно понял и вы хотите хранить использовать стринг как буфер(если это так то это плохая идея).

Comment: Пример (желательно для linux/g++) в студию. / А  для utf-8 я  обычно использую свой [набор функций](http://pastebin.com/iCC2k7RW) ([+ ucsutf.h](http://pastebin.com/gg6Xe9KL)) с которыми можно работать и вообще без locale

Comment: @avp пример чего? Если имеется в виду пример того что ansi == utf8 то придёться поверить на слово потому что рабочего примера на руках нет но есть самописный стринг который проходит все подобные тесты, а он был написан по аналогии с wstring(это не велосипед, у меня свой аллокатор памяти). / Я сильно не вчитывался в код но похоже на какую обёртку аля замена ютфстринга.

Comment: Работающий, например в LANG=en_US.UTF-8, пример `string s; wstring ws; cin >> s; cout << s; wcin >> ws; wcout << ws; ....`

Comment: @avp я понял что вы имеете в виду. спасибо. уточню свой ответ.

Comment: Эм.. С каких пор wstring - это utf8? Вроде же utf16, не?

Comment: @Qwertiy wstring содержит wchar_t (на Windows wchar_t содержит utf-16 code unit, на других системах он достаточно широк, чтобы любой Unicode code point поместился. В любом случае, узкие строки `u8""` (`char`  — байты) это не широкие строки (`wchar_t`). Хотя одно в другое можно преобразовать: [`std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>>().from_bytes(u8"<abc абв αβγ >"); `](http://ideone.com/eUXgg9)